# How to make shared space from HDDs of nodes in a cluster?

Tags: nfs, cluster

I have a 2-node cluster with each node having two HDDs. I want make a scratch space common to both nodes using the second HDD of each cluster. I mounted the 2nd HDD of master node as /home and have an NFS setup for the home dir of mpiuser. Which is the common user for executing parallel jobs. How do I add the 2nd HDD of the slave node to this space ?

Comment: This sounds like a bad idea and will probably end up not working the way you think it will. Try Gluster, it might work well enough.

Comment: Thanks Chris, I think setting up Gluster is the solution !!!